# Searching two elements in two list

Tags: prolog

i have a predicate search(a,b,c,d) that holds if the elemnts in a and b occupy corrisponding list C and D.

Here is my code but it returns false:

```
corresp( X , [X|_] , Y      , [Y|_] ) .
corresp( X , Y     , [_|Xs] , [_|Ys]) :- corresp( X , Xs , Y , Ys ) .
```

it returns false when X AND Y are in the lists

Comment: why not `corresp(X,[_|Xs],Y,[_|Ys]) :- corresp(X,Xs,Y,Ys).` ?

Comment: @CapelliC i changed it to how you have done it and this is what I got:
corresp(1,2,[2,3,1],[3,3,2]).
false.

Comment: sorry, you're right. It's the first clause to change. `corresp(X,Y,[X|_],[Y|_]).` Your second original clause was ok.

Comment: @CapelliC Sorry to be a pain ahha, I changed it to that and this happens..
 corresp(yellow,red,[yellow,pink,red],[blue,red]).
false.

Comment: It only works when the yellow and red are the heads of the lists

Answer (score 0):

Your code sample here:

```
corresp( X , [X|_] , Y      , [Y|_] ) .
corresp( X , Y     , [_|Xs] , [_|Ys]) :- corresp( X , Xs , Y , Ys ) .
```

is inconsistent. Try

```
corresp( X , Y , [X|_] , [Y|_] ).
corresp( X , Y , [_|A] , [_|B] ) :- corresp( X , Y , A , B ) .
```

Whitespace and careful layout help considerably in [grokking](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/G/grok.html) code (your own or someone else's). Cognitive science shows that tabular layouts, in particular, facilitate bug identification as deviations from the normal pattern stand out.